# Merging the last columns of two lists under a rule

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have two lists whose first columns are identical, such as:

```
list1 = {{40., 7.50551*10^-10}, {40.,7.50557*10^-10}, {40.,7.50566*10^-10},
         {40.0001, 7.50578*10^-10}, {40.0001, 7.50591*10^-10},{40.0001, 7.50607*10^-10},
         {40.0002, 7.50625*10^-10}, {40.0002, 7.50645*10^-10},{40.0003, 7.50668*10^-10},
         {40.0003, 7.50692*10^-10}};

list2 = {{40., 0.0712996}, {40., 0.0712996}, {40.,0.0712996}, {40.0001, 0.0712996},
         {40.0001, 0.0712996}, {40.0001, 0.0712996}, {40.0002, 0.0712996},
         {40.0002, 0.0712996}, {40.0003, 0.0712996}, {40.0003, 0.0712996}};
```

How can I multiply corresponding elements of the last column and merge these lists? i.e. keep the first elements intact at each position and multiply the corresponding last elements to generate a new list. In other words, how can the last columns of the two lists be merged under multiplication?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
{list1[[All, 1]], (list1 list2)[[All, 2]]} // Transpose
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great !

Answer (score 4):

```
list1 Inner[{#2,#1}&,list2,{0,1}, #2&]
```

In the example given by the OP (but not in the general case of the question title), all the second elements in `list2` are also identical, and [Dot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) may be used to 'multiply a matrix column by a factor', and get the same result:

```
list1.{{1,0},{0,list2[[1,2]]}}
```

And:

```
(list1 Inner[{#2,#1}&,list2,{0,1}, #2&])===(list1.{{1,0},{0,list2[[1,2]]}})
```

> True

**Yet another method** is the following:

```
list1 ArrayFlatten[{{1, List/@list2[[All,2]]}}]
```

For this use of `ArrayFlatten` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2274679/499167) old SO answer by [Janus](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1308/janus)

**Original Answer**

```
 list1 Inner[{1,#1}&,list2,{1,0}, #2&]
```

Comment: Correct. I had noticed that the first elements for both lists are the same, but had not noticed the second elements of list 2. I can only suppose that the OP is asking for a general example.

Answer (score 3):

The same, but with `Thread`.

```
Thread[{list1[[All, 1]], list2[[All, 2]]*list1[[All, 2]]}]
```

Another way to get the product is

```
Table[list2[[i, 2]]*list1[[i, 2]], {i, 1, Length[list1]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version:

```
MapThread[{#[[1]], #[[2]] #2[[2]]} &, {list1, list2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a =
  {{40., 7.50551}, {40., 7.50557}, {40., 7.50566}, 
   {40.0001, 7.50578}, {40.0001, 7.50591}, {40.0001, 7.50607}, 
   {40.0002, 7.50625}, {40.0002, 7.50645}, {40.0003, 7.50668}, 
   {40.0003, 7.50692}};

b =
  {{40., 0.0712996}, {40., 0.0712996}, {40., 0.0712996}, 
   {40.0001, 0.0712996}, {40.0001, 0.0712996}, 
   {40.0001, 0.0712996}, {40.0002, 0.0712996}, {40.0002, 0.0712996}, 
   {40.0003, 0.0712996}, {40.0003, 0.0712996}};
```

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
SubsetMap[Last /@ (a b) &, a, {All, 2}]
```

returns

```
{{40., 0.53514}, {40., 0.535144}, {40., 0.535151}, {40.0001, 0.535159}, 
 {40.0001, 0.535168}, {40.0001, 0.53518}, {40.0002, 0.535193}, 
 {40.0002, 0.535207}, {40.0003, 0.535223}, {40.0003, 0.53524}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following, but it depends on the lists being identical in size and in their first elements.

```
MapThread[
    Merge[{#1, #2}, Apply[Times]] &, {Rule @@@ a, Rule @@@ b}] //
   Map[KeyValueMap[List]] //
  Map[Apply[Sequence]] //
 Grid
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
l1 = {{40., 7.50551}, {40., 7.50557}, {40., 7.50566}, {40.0001, 
    7.50578}, {40.0001, 7.50591}, {40.0001, 7.50607}, {40.0002, 
    7.50625}, {40.0002, 7.50645}, {40.0003, 7.50668}, {40.0003, 
    7.50692}};

l2 = {{40., 0.0712996}, {40., 0.0712996}, {40., 0.0712996}, {40.0001, 
    0.0712996}, {40.0001, 0.0712996}, {40.0001, 0.0712996}, {40.0002, 
    0.0712996}, {40.0002, 0.0712996}, {40.0003, 0.0712996}, {40.0003, 
    0.0712996}};
```

---

Using `Thread` and `MapApply`:

```
{#[[1]], #[[2]]  #2[[2]]} & @@@ Thread[{a, b}]
```

*Result*:

> {{40., 0.53514}, {40., 0.535144}, {40., 0.535151}, {40.0001,
> 0.535159}, {40.0001, 0.535168}, {40.0001, 0.53518}, {40.0002,
> 0.535193}, {40.0002, 0.535207}, {40.0003, 0.535223}, {40.0003,
> 0.53524}}