# Shifting and adding the columns of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's say that I have this list

```
a={{-2, 1}, {-1, 2}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}}
```

and I'd like to change the value of the elements in the column to obtain something like this

```
b={{-2, 0}, {-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}
```

so, you can see that it's like I'm shifting the values in the column two positions.

and then I'd like to sum the elements in the column to obtain

```
c={{-2, 1}, {-1, 2}, {0, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}
```

Comment: `I'm shifting the values in the column two positions`  btw, it is actually a shift by 3 not 2.

Comment: @Nasser It's three if you rotate to the left but two if you rotate to the right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a = {{-2, 1}, {-1, 2}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}}
before = a[[All, 2]];
a[[All, 2]] = RotateLeft[a[[All, 2]], 3];
a[[All, 2]] = a[[All, 2]] + before;
```

Now `a` is your `c`

### Step-By-Step

```
 (a = {{-2, 1}, {-1, 2}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}}) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
before = a[[All, 2]];
a[[All, 2]] = RotateLeft[a[[All, 2]], 3];
(b = a) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
b[[All, 2]] = b[[All, 2]] + before;
(c = b) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

```
SubsetMap[RotateRight[#,2]&, a, {All,2}]
```

> {{-2, 0}, {-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}

```
%==b
```

> True

For **Part 2**, see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/222548/multiply-each-element-of-second-position-of-two-list/222575#222575) recent question

'Borrowing from the neat [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/222551/106) given by [David Keith](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/44700/david-keith):

```
Transpose[{a[[All,1]],(a+b)[[All,2]]}]==c
```

> True

[Alternatively](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/222575/106):

```
a+ArrayFlatten[{{0, List/@b[[All,2]]}}]==c
```

> True

Comment: And from the answer given by @kglr,  Part 2 may also be obtained as follows: `SubsetMap[#+RotateRight[#,2]&, a, {All,2}]==c`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a one-liner:

```
Transpose@MapAt[# + RotateRight[#, 2] &, Transpose[a], 2]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SubsetMap[Reverse, a, {All, 2}] == b
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
SubsetMap[# + Reverse @ #&, a, {All, 2}] == c
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Or get `b` and `c` in a single step:

```
Rest @ FoldList[SubsetMap[#2, #, {All, 2}] &, a, {Reverse, # + Reverse @ # &}] == {b, c}
```

> ```
> True
> ```